# Does Aloy auto-heal when she is in danger?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I was trying a Hunting Ground and several Tramplers and Glinthawks attacked me ruining my run, I didn't want to waste my medicinal herbs so I waited to simply die and restart. But I noticed that my health bar recovered a little bit when Aloy was in danger (when it's blinking), and it never happened to me before.

Was this feature always available? Or is it a collateral effect of some ability I've unlocked?

Comment: weird...there is no ability that does this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Aloy will recover some health naturally if she has critical health. I do not have specific numbers for you, but I've noticed on multiple occasions that she will recover some health if she takes cover or hides for a few moments.

Comment: It seems to happen also if you are running, but good to know!